# R Heatmap with values below 0 red, above 0 gradient of blue

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I have a heatmap that ranges from -100 to 100. I would like to have any value that is below 0 to be red while values above 0 are a gradient of blue.

I've seen examples of getting gradients of red and blue, but not for red to be constant red.

What I've tried so far:

```
bk = c(seq(-100,-0.1,length=1), seq(-0.1,0.1,length=1), seq(0.1,100,length=100))
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("red"))
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("blue"))(length(bk)-1)
hmcols <- c(rc1, rc2)
```

but I get the error

```
"Error in image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +  : 
  must have one more break than colour"
```

Comment: bk = c(seq(-100,-0.1,length=1), seq(-0.1,0.1,length=1), seq(0.1,100,length=100))
rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("red"))
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("blue"))(length(bk)-1)
hmcols <- c(rc1, rc2)

Comment: What heat map plotting function are you using? Can you give the command you are using to draw the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of such a plot

```
#breaks
bk <- c(-100,seq(0,100,by=10))
#colors (one less than breaks
mycols <- c("red",colorRampPalette(colors = c("white","blue"))(length(bk)-2))

#sample data
z <- matrix(runif(25*25, -100, 100), ncol=25)

#plot
heatmap(z, col=mycols, breaks=bk, scale="none")
```

[image]

Notice that to get the particular colors you want, we use one call to `colorRampPalette` passing in the three colors you want to transition between (assuming white is an acceptable neutral color for the middle range). We also use `scale="none"` because by default it will scale the values between 0 and 1. So if you want to keep the breaks on the original range of values, you'll need to disable the scaling.

Comment: Thanks for your response MrFlick, however, I want anything below 0 to be just red, not a shade of red.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. (You shouldn't accept answers till they are correct).

Comment: Oops, I am new to stackoverflow and wasn't sure what the difference between the green check vs up arrow.

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly for my purpose. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad it works and is now deserving of the green check. Sorry I misread the question the first time.